# Matlab, Interpolate data between two vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, interpolation

So I'm currently working on filling a 2-D matrix in order to calibrate a picture I've taken.

To do so I've created:

```
vector1 = linspace(0.037, 0.03175, 256);
```

This vector is ideally the first row in the matrix.

I then have another vector:

```
vector2 = linspace(0.0288, 0.0277, 256);
```

I was wondering if there is any way to interpolate between `vector1` and `vector2` and have them be inserted into a matrix with `Row 1 = vector1` and `Row 168 = vector2`.

I should have 168 total rows, with 256 columns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'd rather not have to do 168 rows manually....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want simple linear interpolation between the two, you can apply a weight to each of the vectors `V1` and `V2` and add them together. At the top, `V1` will be weighted by `1` and `V2` should be weighted by `0`. Similarly at the bottom, `V2` should be weighted by `1` and `V1` should be weighted by `0`. Every where else the weights should add to `1` and will weight `V1` and `V2` based upon how close the row is to the top or bottom.

```
V3 = alpha * V1 + (1 - alpha) * V2;
```

We can use matrix multiplication to create the weighted versions of `V1` and `V2` and then add the result together to get `V3`.

```
nRows = 168;

alpha = linspace(1, 0, nRows);
V3 = alpha(:) * V1 + (1 - alpha(:)) * V2;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can just use `interp1` as follows:

```
m = interp1([1 2],[vector1;vector2],linspace(1,2,168))
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked flawlessly. Thank you

Comment: you can also play with different interpolation methods (spline, cubic etc)... look into the documentation of `interp1`

Comment: (the linear interpolation is the default)

Answer (score 1):

While for your specific application it is probably overkill, but you can use `griddata` to perform 2d bilinear interpolation using your input points. This would not necessarily give the same result as a manual 1d interpolation of your data, although in this specific case I believe the result will probably be the same:

```
H = 168;
W = 256;
vector1 = linspace(0.037,0.03175,W);
vector2 = linspace(0.0288,0.0277,W);
[Wmat,Hmat] = meshgrid(1:W,1:H);
img = griddata([1:W,1:W],[ones(1,W), H*ones(1,W)],[vector1 vector2],Wmat,Hmat,'linear')
```

The result seems to be correct:

```
>> all(abs(img(1,:)-vector1)<1e-10)

ans =

     1

>> all(abs(img(end,:)-vector2)<1e-10)

ans =

     1
```